# Getting compilation error while converting number to words in jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

In `Jasperstudio` I have added `ConvertToWord plugin jar` in classpath for converting number to word and created the scriplet, included fully qualified class name in scriplet properties after referring Jasperstudio tutorials.

**num.jrxml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-09-08T12:45:28 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="num" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7a5c9b49-9dc5-422a-ac69-e92cf61ef530">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample1"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <scriptlet name="REPORT" class="com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from userntow]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="salary" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="salary1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{salary}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="725" y="0" width="77" height="102" uuid="651ccc4b-e999-40fe-bcbf-1f25bcfc98af"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="721" height="66" backcolor="#000000" uuid="d8d9e644-3a32-491d-97cb-a277aff17133"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="66" uuid="27d8f6ee-f0a9-44f6-a160-1763c3b00f30"/>
                    <box topPadding="4" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="4"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry Title]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="370" y="37" width="316" height="29" uuid="cfa21334-0634-4605-9ea7-aca4981f67e4"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry SubTitle]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="70" width="721" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000" uuid="b0c895f6-6dbd-477d-9858-9ad66af087e1"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="553" y="12" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a33fce3b-20c1-4696-873a-fe134d1e7d88"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="06a70999-03a2-403a-994e-a387a021b4ef"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="265" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="57af4e0f-b095-441d-b0b7-2727312ffc03"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[salary]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="530" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="f0a7d2a9-5d50-46fe-874b-9b7849393693"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="797" height="18" uuid="34a2ae4b-4055-476b-8676-d499f6af510b"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="265" height="18" uuid="cfbfb7f7-04e0-42c6-86eb-aa91a4fc8c12"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="265" y="0" width="265" height="18" uuid="9434a0ca-26d2-4603-8812-dad5452b3522"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{salary}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="530" y="0" width="265" height="18" uuid="ffb6b7cd-2a48-4a39-9d75-57e199d9105b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="501ac6c4-e9d4-43cb-ba6b-7f2f44394cf3"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="25" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000" uuid="ffb10ec8-0371-4545-8eaa-96d62ad3cec0"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="757" y="3" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b5521ea6-5f36-4864-856f-58d0bcd011f2"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="677" y="3" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e625ea3c-1741-4cfe-81cf-fbbdd00162c8"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="3" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0c9f7e91-d3f5-47f9-82b7-0b2b3a43a5d6"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="240" y="3" width="380" height="30" uuid="c1a499d4-5e1d-4f70-8af4-63f891465a18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET} .readNumber($V{salary1})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="3" width="100" height="30" uuid="d160f515-04c1-4725-aae4-1b5ac1e49b59"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{salary1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

TextField Expression for converting number to word I have added is

```
   $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET} .readNumber($V{salary1}).
```

where `readNumber` is a method present in ConvertToWord class which I have imported.

Jasperstudio is not identifying method from the imported jar and getting the below **compilation error**.

> the methodreadNumber(Integer)is undefined for the type JRAbstractScriplet.

Comment: try to give it statically like this `<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord.readNumber($V{salary1})]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: there should not be any space between `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}` and  `.readNumber($V{salary1})` try like this `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.readNumber($V{salary1})`

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any space between parameter and method, it should be like this

```
$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.readNumber($V{salary1})
```

for more info on ConvertToWord visit [this](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/docs/ConvertToWord_User_Manual.pdf) document.